# How to return NULL/empty space when the expected property doesn't exist in some of verxtes /edges

Tags: properties, gremlin, vertex, edges, gremlinpython

I am getting the following error, because some of the vertexes don't have the expected property.

```
The property does not exist as the key has no associated value for the provided element
```

Query:-

```
get_g().V().hasLabel(search_vertex).has(T.id, TextP.containing(search_text)).limit(limit). 
        as_('property_value').inE('owns').outV().as_('id', 'name')
        .select('property_value', 'id', 'name').by(T.id).by(T.id).by('name').toList()
```

How to avoid exception and return `NULL` or `empty space`, if the expected property doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version of TinkerPop before 3.5.0 you can accomplish this using `coalesce()` (details [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#coalesce-step)) and `constant()` (details [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#constant-step)) steps to return a specific value in the case that a value does not exist as shown here:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').select('a').by(coalesce(values('age'), constant('foo')))
==>29
==>27
==>foo
==>32
==>foo
==>35
```

In versions after 3.5 this is no longer required as `null` will now be returned for these values, assuming the database supports this, as shown here:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').select('a').by(values('age'))
==>29
==>27
==>null
==>32
==>null
==>35
```

Additional details on this change can be found in this post on the Gremlin users group: https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/aoaA25H1IE0/m/gTu1MqR1AQAJ

Comment: Any idea of `coalesce() and constant()`  class/package in gremlinpython?

Comment: They should both be in `from gremlin_python.process.traversal import *`